# How to produce this type of wave?

Tags: wave, waveform

Can we use  Virtuoso Cadence to produce this type of wave(c,first picture)?it is the wave that PZT produced

[image]

My schematic and waveform of connecting high pass
[image]

Comment: Square wave through an RC highpass. Values depend on the required time constants. My ogle-o-meter says a pulse of 1s period, 50% duty cycle, C=22u, R=1k. Adjust by preference.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen after connecting it,but the output wave is still a square wave ,strange!

Comment: Can you modify your answer to include your attempt?

Comment: Your original image works in seconds, whereas your new attempt works in nanoseconds. You will have to adapt the time constant by a factor of 5e-8 to get the same response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using a 1.8V amplitude pulse, why? I don't know, since your image clearly shows a peak of `60mV`. Also, you are using a `ns` time scale, despite teh fact that I explicitly said a `1s` period. Maybe you work better with visual clues (clues that are explicit in nature):

[image: pulse]

In case you're not familiar with LTspice, the source, `V1`, a `PULSE` type, from `0V` to `60mV`, `1Hz` frequency, and `50%` duty cycle. The simulation time, if it's obscured by the waveform display, is `2s`.